# Invalid Salt with Python 3, Django and Bcrypt

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, bcrypt

I am trying to port my login/registration module from python 2.7 to python3.5. The code is working fine under 2.7 but when I moved it all to 3.5 I am now getting an invalid salt when I do the password comparison. The code I have to load it into the database is as follows:

```
password = bcrypt.hashpw(request.POST['password'].encode(),bcrypt.gensalt())
new_user = User.objects.create(first_name = first_name, 
  last_name=last_name, email = email, birthday = birthday)
Password.objects.create(pwd = password, user = User.objects.get
   (id = new_user.id))enter code here
```

There are no errors when the information gets inserted. The code for the password check is then as follows:

```
user = User.objects.filter(email = request.POST['email'])[0]
password=bcrypt.checkpw(request.POST['password'].encode(),user.password.pwd.encode())
```

The environment is Python 3.55, Django 2 and Bcrypt. I really need some help on this and I have spent hours looking for an answer and not really able to find one. Thank you one and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the password as utf8 since python 3 string is by default utf8.

```
request.POST['password'].encode('utf-8')
```

This is the issue from the [flask-bcrypt github](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt/issues/9).

Comment: So even after adding the utf8 on the original load into the database and also on the password check I am still getting an invalid salt error.

Comment: Yeah!! Finally got it fixed. The problem was when it is loaded into the database. After the hash has been completed the hashed password needs to be decoded prior to loading into the database. So the new password load needs to be: Password.objects.create(pwd = password.decode('utf-8'), user = User.objects.get(id = new_user.id)). Still not sure why exactly but it works.