# Invalid salt when logging in via django admin panel

Tags: python, django, bcrypt

I'm having some trouble hosting a django API on a separate server. When using localhost everything works, however when I log in to the server admin panel I get an "invalid salt" error.

Originally, I had my own login method that used bcrypt, but I decided to scrap that in favor of using facebook authentication. I've removed all references to bcrypt from my views. The problem lies with the built in admin interface. I haven't modified the code for that at all, but I am unable to log in. I can share my code, but I'm not even sure what files would be relevant to share, so I'm happy to update as needed.

Comment: Does this answer valid to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49891708/8528141?

Comment: @YasserMohsen no. In that question they are using bcrypt for their own login implementation. I'm having trouble with django's built in admin login. I didn't implement this, it's part of the framework.

Comment: So, please share all the related steps and code.

Comment: Like I said in the original post, I'm not even sure what portions of the code are relevant. I solved the problem though, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this wasn't a code problem, it was a dependency problem. I had `py-bcrypt` installed on the server, but not `bcrypt`. It seems both libraries are necessary for the admin feature to work. I probably should have dockerized it.